# react.js react Native Array traversal, click function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I used 'setState' to update the array by clicking the function, I found that If the added element is already contained in the array, it will not only increase the length of the array, but also replace the old elements with new ones.

Below is the code:

```
determineOrder = (obj) => {
    let list = this.state.orderList
    
    obj.key = list.length.toString()
    
    list.push(obj)
    console.log(list)
    this.setState({ orderList: list })
}


this.state.detailList.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.blockStyle]} key={index} onPress={()=>determineOrder(item)}>
             <Text style={styles.font} >{this.props.translate ? item.cnName : item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
    )
 })
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1Q4A.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iONPK.png)

Comment: why do you need those images? you can just edit text code that you pasted adding this comments and removing images at all. images adding extra not necessary misunderstanding when reading your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting the same object into the array again. In Javascript Objects are a reference type. Updating `obj.key` will update the existing object in the array, since it's the same object.

You need to create a new copy of the object.

```
const clone = Object.assign({}, obj);
clone.key = list.length.toString();
list.push(clone);
```

Note: [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) won't deep copy the nested objects. Alternate approach could be to use `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

```
const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't update the state with operations like push. You are assign to list your state and it keep the reference if you want to copy you should make a clone of it and not a reference like let list = [...this.state.orderList]

```
determineOrder = (obj) => {
    
    obj.key = list.length.toString()
    
    list.push(obj)
    console.log(list)
    this.setState((prevState) => { 
    return {
             ...prevState, 
             orderList: [...prevState.orderList, obj]
           }
    });
}


this.state.detailList.map((item, index) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.blockStyle]} key={index} onPress={()=>determineOrder(item)}>
             <Text style={styles.font} >{this.props.translate ? item.cnName : item.name}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity> 
    )
 })
```